# How to delete all the content and not mapping in elasticsearch index using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an index called event which has around 250 records. I want to delete this 250 records without deleting the full mapping.

```
DeleteIndex delete = new DeleteIndex.Builder("events").build();
client.execute(delete);
```

the above code deletes the full event index. How can to only delete the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on ElasticSearch documentation [**Delete By Query API**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), you can delete all documents within an index using a query as following :

```
POST twitter/tweet/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

With [ElasticSearch Java API "Delete By Query API" documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.1/java-docs-delete-by-query.html) :

```
BulkByScrollResponse response =
    DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
        .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("gender", "male")) 
        .source("persons")                                  
        .get();                                             

long deleted = response.getDeleted();
```

Please note that this answer is suitable for **ElasticSearch 6.1** but may differ for other versions of ElasticSearch.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using spring data I was able to resolve this issue using deleteAll funtion.

```
eventRepo.deleteAll();
```

did the trick for me.